# What is the equivalent of autoruns tool in linux for finding suspicious startup executables?

Tags: malware, linux, forensics

In Windows, Autoruns tool is a really helpful tool for forensic investigators to help them find suspicious startup executables and filter the benign ones.

but i couldn't anything good like this in linux, so what is the easiest way to achieve what autoruns does in finding suspicious startup apps? any tool like that in linux?

basically lets say you are a forensic investigator and you are given a linux system like Ubuntu, and are asked to find suspicious startup executables, how will you do it and what tools will you use to fasten the process?

Comment: This looks fun and might be worth a look: "THOR Lite includes the file system and process scan module as well as module that extracts “autoruns” information on the different platforms." > https://www.nextron-systems.com/thor-lite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> basically lets say you are a forensic investigator and you are given a linux
> system like Ubuntu, and are asked to find suspicious startup executables, how
> will you do it and what tools will you use to fasten the process?

You can inspect every program executed on a machine using
[forkstat](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ecking/forkstat/). The output will contain
a ton of noise due to the sheer amount of processes spawning at any given time,
but the list you obtain through this should be exhaustive. [0]

Let’s assume the kernel on the system you’re analyzing has the
[`NETLINK_CONNECTOR`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/connector/connector.txt)
functionality enabled and your forkstat binary is not compromised, e. g. you
compiled and deployed it yourself.
You have to decide how early you want it to start listening for events.
Create a unit file and hook into the [system startup](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html)
at an appropriate moment, e. g. `basic.target`:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/forkstat.service 
[Unit]
Description=process sniffer

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/forkstat

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Verify that it works by starting the service and observing the result with
`journalctl -f`. The forkstat output will then be captured in the system
journal. Note that this is a really early on during startup, before the root
filesystem is even available, so for this to work *the forkstat binary must be
available in the initrd*. How you add it to the initrd depends on the distro.
For Arch it’s as simple as adding it to the `BINARIES=…` line in
`mkinitcpio.conf`.

Enable the service, rebuild the initrd, reboot. After the new boot you can
use `journalctl -b` to review the captured events:

```
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com systemd[1]: Started process sniffer.
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: Time     Event     PID Info   Duration Process
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 exec      321                 [/sbin/modprobe -q -- iptable_nat]
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 fork        1 parent          /sbin/init
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 fork      322 child           /sbin/init
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 exit      313      0   0.610s /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 fork        2 parent          [kthreadd]
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 fork      323 child           [kthreadd]
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 fork      265 parent          /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
Dec 04 10:12:17 zombo.com forkstat[318]: 10:12:17 fork      324 child           /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
```

You will be interested mostly in the `parent` and `child` lines which
indicate what process executed which binary. I’ll refer you to the [forkstat
manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/forkstat/forkstat.8.en.html)
for the details.

Caution: Since this is an exhaustive overview of process spawning activity, the
journal can get quite big. Make sure you set the journal limits to
appropriately large values to accommodate the tremendous amount of log
messages generated.

Also note that the veracity of this output depends on a trustworthy
kernel. If you suspect the kernel itself has been compromised, rootkit
style, you may want to deploy a known trustworthy kernel first.

[0] On a really busy system some events might get dropped which is an artifact
of the underlying netlink API that forkstat uses.

Answer (score 1):

So coming from Windows will frame your view of things. I've trod the same path.

First is to understand how Linux does autostart. You need to know about init/systemd and you need to be aware that Linux has multiple DEs to choose from (Desktop Environments) though there is some common plumbing in home user directories, for example with KDE: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/index.html

Thus, given how easy it is to work with the Linux file system and configuration data, it is rudimentary to interrogate via the CLI and does not necessarily require a graphical client.

Given this is something new for you I can suggest investigating this project that can automate some tasks for you: https://cisofy.com/lynis/ < this is by the author of rootkit hunter (rkhunter) for Linux, a great tool and something else you might wish to consider during your audit, i.e. rogue executables *and* rootkits.